# Webdriver does not timeout despite of timeout set

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have set the timeouts in webdriver as follows:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But the webdriver sometimes gets stuck on "transfering data from somewebsite.somedomain.com..." and does not throw a Timeout exception.

Why is that happening and how do I get rid of this situation?

I am using selenium webdriver version 2.45.0

Comment: what other exception is it throwing then? do the webpage opens finally?

Comment: @Manu No exception. Nothing happens. It simply keeps loading that page. And after a lot of time, it moves to next statement. I want to have a sort of DEFINITE way to time it out.

Comment: does this happen when you navigate to other URL? I believe you should edit the question to elaborate the scenario you are working on as timeout is working fine at my end

Comment: Are you setting timeout after driver.get? Also you can try out to check state of page for some counters.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try if any explicit wait works, ie: Load\navigate to the page, and use explicit wait on any of the UI object on that page.
Like:

```
    WebElement MydynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 25))
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated("By some locator")));
```